# IE8 and below <input type="image"> value work around

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I have a slight problem, I am trying to capture the input of two buttons, one yes, one no, into a database but for some reason the database doesn't always show the value of the button clicked, it just shows up blank.

```
<form  action="refer.php" method="post" id="formID" >
  <div class="prompt_container" style="float: left;">
    <span class="prompt_item"><input type="image" src="images/yes.jpg"
      alt="submit" value="yes" onclick="this.disabled=true,this.form.submit();"
      /></span>
    <input type="hidden" name="refer" value="yes">
  </div>
</form>

<form action="thank_you.php" method="post" id="formID" >
  <div class="prompt_container" style="float: right;">
    <span class="prompt_item"><input type="image" src="images/no.jpg"
      alt="submit" value="no" onclick="this.disabled=true,this.form.submit();"
      /></span>
    <input type="hidden" name="refer" value="no" >
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is the code that writes it all to the database

```
session_start();

$name = $_SESSION['name'];

$tel = $_SESSION['tel'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$refer = $_POST['refer'];
$curDate = date("Y-m-d");

mysql_connect ("host", "user", "pass") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("database");

$query = "INSERT INTO Table (id, name, tel, email, refered, date)
  VALUES('NULL', '".$name."', '".$tel."', '".$email."', '".$refer."', '".$curDate."')";

mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

Apparently anything lower than IE8 will ignore the value attribute of all `<input type="image">` form inputs.

How could I get this to work properly in all browsers? jQuery or Javascript maybe?

Comment: Could you show us your code? Something as basic as form fields should work in pretty much all browsers in use today.

Comment: can you elaborate the issue? You might probably show your implementation HTML part.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the code quickly.

Comment: I don't understand, you're disabling the buttons which would cause them to not be sent to the server AND you don't have a name for the buttons so the server doesn't know what to call them

Comment: @Chris Haas - The idea I think is that the "refer" value gets posted instead.

Comment: @Alohci, sorry, a combination of the title and not enough coffee is confusing me apparently

Comment: @Chris I am not disabling them, they still get written to the database, it just blocks double submits, and I am using the "refer" value instead of the name.

Comment: @kielie, the code "this.disabled=true" disables the form button and disabled form fields don't get sent to the server.

Comment: @kielie FYI: the line where you're building your query could be cleaned up by using variable interpolation, a feature of PHP's double-quote strings.  Instead of ending the string and appending the variable and reopening the string, just embed them right in the string:
`... VALUES('NULL', '$name', '$tel', '$email', '$refer', '$curDate')";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is presumably that given a click at co-ordinates (1,2) on:

```
<input type="image" name="foo" value="bar"/>
```

IE will pass:

```
foo.x=1&foo.y=2
```

where other browsers will pass:

```
foo=bar&foo.x=1&foo.y=2
```

So to make image inputs work cross-browser you need to be sniffing for the existence of the `name.x` parameter and not merely `name`.

If you need to have two different image buttons, that means they will need to have two separate names instead of relying on different `value`​s that might not get parsed:

```
<input type="image" name="foo.bar"/>
<input type="image" name="foo.bof"/>
```

And then at the server side check for the existence of parameters `foo.bar.x` and `foo.bof.x`.

[edit re: edit]

```
<input type="image" value="yes"/>
```

This won't work. Without a `name` attribute, the `image` input isn't a successful control, so the `value` won't be passed, and co-ordinate data may not be passed either.

```
<input type="hidden" name="refer" value="yes">
```

Both hidden inputs will be submitted, regardless of which `image` is clicked. The successfulness of the `image` input doesn't affect the successfulness of any other `hidden` element.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Table (id, name, tel, email, refered, date) VALUES('NULL', '".$name."', '".$tel."', '".$email."', '".$refer."', '".$curDate."')";
```

That's some pretty dangerous SQL injection there. You should make friends with `mysql_real_escape_string` or parameterised queries.

Comment: So I would look for something like POST_['foo.bar.x'] ?
Or am I misunderstanding the situation?

Comment: Yes, if an `<input type="image" name="something">` is clicked, you'll get a `something.x` parameter with a numeric value in all browsers.

Comment: If its PHP you would look for `$_POST[foo.bar_x]` or maybe `$_POST[foo_bar_x]`. PHP is odd.

Comment: Thanks David, I had completely forgotten about that. It is indeed a very strange feature. Another victim of the foulness that is register_globals, I suppose. I used names with dots as a signal that I'm hacking the desired value into the name, but yeah, probably best avoid this in PHP and just use eg. `$_POST['actionone_x']` and `$_POST['actiontwo_x']`.

Comment: So if I use $_POST[foo_bar_x]  it should work in all browsers?

Comment: @bobince I'll have a look at the SQl injection, thanx for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

Give the inputs different **names** check for the presence of `name.x` in the submitted data.

Answer (score 0):

i noticed that you are disabling your inputs before you submit the form.

**you cant do that**, if you want to submit the values of those inputs. disabled inputs are **not submitted**.

what you need to do is copy the value to some hidden inputs first.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?